# Can we take bath in the evening after deepam has been lit?

Tags: rituals, sandhyavandanam

Before performing *sandhyavandanam* in the evening, should a *brahmin* take bath? Or do the *shastras* prohibit it?

We live in southern Chennai and there are times when the sun sets well over 6 or 6:30 p.m. During such times, in case I plan to take bath immediately before starting *sandhyavandanam*, it's five to ten minutes past six, and my mom already lights the *deepam*.

Can I still take bath after the *deepam* has been lit?

Comment: Bathing and Sandhya Gyatri japa Should not be done after Sunset.

Comment: The japa should be halted/stopped when nakshatras(constellations)  are visible (i.e when the Sandhi kala(meeting of two times day and night at horizon))is over. That is the end of sandhyakala or the time for Sandhyavandanam. In morning it is time after sunrise but for those who are late at sandhyavandana in both kalas (upto a 45 min or 50 min) duration can do Prayaschitta Arghya for clearing the sin of doing sandhyavandana late and then should perform minimum japa (i.e. with minimum japa sankhya e.g. 28 bramhin savitri mantra).

Comment: @Yogi Please correct me if I'm wrong. Since arghyam has to be given at the sandhya time, doesn't it follow that a part of gayatri japam comes after the sun has fully set? Is that a dosham?

Comment: @Yogi If that is indeed wrong, can you tell me by what time we should finish sayam sandhya (including gayatri japam, digdevata namaskar, etc.)?

Comment: Digdevta namaskar and the epilouge part can be done/performed after sunset.

Comment: @Yogi So, in case someone plans to do japa for over half an hour, he should commence sandhyavandanam well before sunset, give arghyam when the sun hasn't touched the horizon, and then continue with the japa, shouldn't he? That way, within another 30 to 40 minutes, it'd be time to end. Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37959/discussion-between-yogi-and-mahesh).

Comment: I believe gayatri japa can be done any time. instead of leaving the karma altogether you can do yadsakthi.. im taking snana and doing it regularly in the evening.. if you don't do it.. then next janma will be lower than this..

Answer (score 1):

The thumb rule of Sandhyavandanam is, you do the "Arghya Pradhanam" during sun rise and sun set. Before the sun rise and after sun set, we should not perform this ritual. These days, due to our lifestyle, we are unable to perform it at the right time. Hence, we have an alternative of pryaschitta, by doing more number of japa for delaying the pratah and sayam kala sandhyavandanam. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/36302)

Answer (score 0):

Also, taking bath is prohibited at sandhya kalam. So if you live in such a place where taking bath in the evening is a must due to weather conditions, please do it before the sunset. Once lights are put on, you should not take bath. All the other practices of taking bath after 12:00pm, taking bath late evening or night is for different cause, hope you connect these dots.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/36303)